# Regex - remove non-5 digit zips from a string

Tags: php, regex

My Zip code string needs to look like this:

11111 22222 33333 44444 55555 etc.

If a customer puts in 11111, 22222, 33333, 55555 or anything else not 5 numbers (digits) followed or preceded by 1 optional space,  I want it to remove the bad ones and leave the proper ones

So, for example, if someone puts in 11111 2222A 33333, it should just return 11111 33333, or if they put in 11111, 22222, 33333, it should return 11111 22222 33333.  I also want it to return properly if they do 11111,22222,33333 but I know how to replace commas with spaces I think so I can check that seperately

My regex tests so far have been these:

```
$data = '11111 2222A 33333';
// Attempt 1
$x = preg_replace('/^([\s]*\d{5})+[\s]*$/','',$data);

// Attempt 2
$y = preg_replace('/[^\s?(?=\d{5})(?=\s?)*]/','',$data);
$x = preg_replace('/!\d{5}\s?/','',$y);

// Attempt 3
$x = preg_replace('/[^\b\d{5}\b\s]/','',$data);

return $x;
```

I'm trying to replace the things that don't match 5 digits followed by or preceded by a space (optional so it matches first zipcodes and ending zipcodes in the string) with nothing, effectively removing them.

But so far all it does is remove the A in 2222A and leaves the 2222.  Only one attempt would not be commented out at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `preg_match_all` followed by optional `implode` call:

```
$s = '11111, 22222, 33333'
preg_match_all('/\b\d{5}\b/', $s, $m);
echo implode(' ', $m[0]);
//=> 11111 22222 33333

$s = '11111,22222,33333'
preg_match_all('/\b\d{5}\b/', $s, $m);
echo implode(' ', $m[0]);
//=> 11111 22222 33333

$s = '11111,2222A,33333'
preg_match_all('/\b\d{5}\b/', $s, $m);
echo implode(' ', $m[0]);
//=> 11111 33333
```

Comment: Didn't know about preg_match_all, very nice and exactly what I wanted.  Thank you much.